# Copy the File Structure from one Team to another with Powershell using MS Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was trying to copy the whole Team with a folderstructur to another. However, I ran into the problem that I don't know how to copy the whole structure.

The first part with the channels I do with the /teams/{teamsid}/clone

The second part I create in a first step the channel folders to fill them with the subfolders.

What I tried: But this Script just creates the Channel Folders and their direct subfolders

```
#Update Variables
$customername = $customername.replace(' ','')
$URLCloneFolder        = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?" + "$" + "filter=displayName eq '$customername'"
# Give MS Graph Time to create Group
$group = ''
Do {
    $group = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLCloneFolder -ContentType application/json -Headers $headerParams -Method GET
    Start-Sleep -s 5
}
while ($group.value.Length -eq 0)
$groupid = $group.value.id
$URLBaseTeamChannels = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$teamid/channels"
$BaseTeamChannelNames = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLBaseTeamChannels -ContentType application/json -Headers $headerParams -Method GET

$i=0
while ($i -lt $BaseTeamChannelNames.'@odata.count'){
    $URLCloneFolder = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupid/drive/root/children"
    $body = '{
    "name": "' + $BaseTeamChannelNames.value.displayName.Get($i) + '",
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}'
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLCloneFolder -Headers $headerParams -Body $body -Method POST -ContentType “application/json; charset=utf-8”
    $URLCloneFolder = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$teamid/drive/root/children"
    $children = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLCloneFolder -Headers $headerParams -Method GET -ContentType “application/json; charset=utf-8”
    $childCount = $children.value.folder.childCount.Get($i)
    while ($childCount -gt 0) {
        $childCount -= 1
        $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$teamid/drive/root:/" + $BaseTeamChannelNames.value.displayName.Get($i) + ":/children"
        $childrenObjects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $headerParams -Method GET -ContentType “application/json; charset=utf-8”
        $childrenname = $childrenObjects.value.name.Get($childCount)
        $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupid/drive/root:/" + $BaseTeamChannelNames.value.displayName.Get($i) + "/" + $childrenname
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $headerParams -Body "{""folder"": {}}" -Method PUT -ContentType “application/json; charset=utf-8”
    }
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Please post you code as plain text, not screenshots of code. [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70971391/edit) and paste the code at the bottom (we can help you format it correctly after the fact)

Comment: @yamaro - Are you facing any error while running the script?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft No, theres no error

Comment: @yamaro - Could you please share which document you are referring for this.

Comment: @yamaro - Could you please elaborate what exactly the wholestructure consist. As you said channel folders and direct subfolders are already created.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy the whole structure of Team.
You can copy the following parts in Team using **POST /teams/{id}/clone** Graph API

- apps - Copies Microsoft Teams apps that are installed in the team.
- channels – Copies the channel structure (but not the messages in the channel).
- members – Copies the members and owners of the group.
- settings – Copies all settings within the team, along with key group settings.
- tabs – Copies the tabs within channels.

Ref doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http